# Objective-C init function not initializing correctly

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface Set : NSObject
{
// instance variables
int repetitions;
int weight;
}
// functions
- (id)init;
- (id)initWithReps: (int)newRepetitions andWeight: (int)newWeight;

@implementation Set
-(id)init
{
if (self = [super init]) {
    repetitions = 0;
    weight = 0;
}
return self;
}

-(id)initWithReps: (int)newRepetitions andWeight: (int)newWeight
{
if (self = [super init]) 
{
    repetitions = newRepetitions;
    weight = newWeight;
}
return self;
}

@implementation eFit2Tests

- (void)setUp
{
[super setUp];
// Set-up code here.
}

- (void)tearDown
{
// Tear-down code here. 
[super tearDown];
}

- (void)testInitWithParam
{
Set* test = nil;
test = [test initWithReps:10 andWeight:100];
NSLog(@"Num Reps: %d", [test reps]);
if([test reps] != 10) {
    STFail(@"Reps not currectly initialized. (initWithParam)");
}
NSLog(@"Weight: %d", [test weight]);
if([test weight] != 100) {
    STFail(@"Weight not currectly initialized. (initWithParam)");
}
}
```

For some reason the test at the bottom of this code snippet fails because the values of repetitions and weight are always equal to 0. I come from a background in Java and am clueless as to why this is the case. Sorry for the silly question...

Answer (score 3):

You are setting `test` to nil, and then sending it `initWithReps:andWeight:`. This is equivalent to `[nil initWithReps:10 andWeight:100]`, which obviously isn't what you want. `nil` just responds to any message with itself or 0, so that init message is returning nil and sending `reps` to nil is returning 0.

To create an object, you want the `alloc` class method — i.e. `Set *test = [[Set alloc] initWithReps:10 andWeight:100]`. (And if you're not using ARC, you'll want to release this object when you're finished with it, per the memory management guidelines.)

Answer (score 1):

Where you're initializing your set, replace it with:

```
Set *test = [[Set alloc] initWithReps: 10 andWeight: 100];
```

You're getting 0 because that's the default return from a nil object (you've initialized test to nil) - there are no NullPointerExceptions in Objective-C